# Can't get around "Failed to register a ServiceWorker" SSL cert error

Tags: javascript, angular, ssl, service-worker

This is my first attempt to use push notifications, and also my first time trying to create a service worker to receive those notifications.

My self-signed certificate *is working* for all three of these other things:

1. My Angular app via `ng serve`
2. My API server
3. Proxying my API server through `ng serve` like this:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://localhost:4201",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

This code is failing, however:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/assets/service.js').then(reg =>
      console.log('Service worker registration succeeded:', reg))
      .catch(err => console.error('Service worker registration failed:', err));
  }
```

...with this error:

> DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost:4200/assets/') with script ('https://localhost:4200/assets/service.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.

I've registered my self-cert both with Windows and Chrome.

I've configured Chrome to ignore cert errors from localhost.

I've tried launching Chrome using command line arguments telling Chrome to ignore cert errors from `https://localhost:4200`

None of these workarounds that I've found suggested in my search for answers so far are getting me anywhere.

I doubled checked that I've got the correct path to my service script by deliberately breaking that path, and then receiving a 404 error instead of a cert error.

**UPDATE:** The service registers without a problem using Firefox. It's just Chrome giving me grief.

Comment: *"I've configured Chrome to ignore cert errors from localhost."* It's probably not honored everywhere. And for localhost you don't need HTTPS.

Comment: @gre_gor, from what I've read the push protocol I'm trying to use requires HTTPS, localhost or not. It's weird that Chrome is giving me grief even when I try the various means it has for lowering security, while Firefox is working fine without any special effort.

Comment: Localhost is considered [a secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts) without HTTPS.

Comment: I am trying to access https://{LAN}:{PORT} and getting this error because I need to run it from my mobile device. Any way to tell Chrome Android to treat {LAN} as localhost or something? Does chrome://inspect allow anything like this?